# struct with dynamic chars**, showing first char* as blank after adding 5th entry

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct of dynamic chars, shorts and integers arrays. When I  update the size, everything works up to size 4. When I an additional entry, for some reason the first entry to the dynamic `char` array ends up showing blank instead of the `chars` I was expecting.

However, if I instantiate a struct with 5+ entries, I have no problems.

What is going on? Below is my code & what gets logged to my terminal

```
typedef struct network {
  int count;
  char **ips;
  short *ports;
  int *heartbeat;
  int *local_time;
} network;

network *create_network(char *ip, short port) {
  network *n = malloc(sizeof(network));
  n->count = 1;
  n->ips = malloc(sizeof(char *));
  n->ports = malloc(sizeof(short));
  n->heartbeat = malloc(sizeof(int));
  n->local_time = malloc(sizeof(int));

  n->ips[0] = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  memset(n->ips[0], '\0', INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  strcpy(n->ips[0], ip);
  n->ports[0] = port;
  n->heartbeat[0] = 0;
  n->local_time[0] = 0;
  return n;
}

void update_network(network *current, network *new, int local_time) {

  current->count++;
  current->ips = realloc(current->ips, sizeof(char *) * current->count);
  current->ips[current->count - 1] = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  strcpy(current->ips[current->count - 1], new->ips[0]);

  current->ports = realloc(current->ports, sizeof(short) * current->count);
  current->ports[current->count - 1] = new->ports[0];

  current->heartbeat =
      realloc(current->heartbeat, sizeof(int) * current->count);
  current->heartbeat[current->count - 1] = new->heartbeat[0];

  printf("after heartbeat: %s:%i\n", current->ips[0], current->ports[0]);

  current->local_time[current->count - 1] = local_time;
  printf("after localtime: %s:%i\n", current->ips[0], current->ports[0]);
}

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
  char *ip = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
  ip = "0.0.0.0";

  network *n1 = create_network(ip, 80);
  network *n2 = create_network(ip, 81);
  network *n3 = create_network(ip, 82);
  network *n4 = create_network(ip, 83);
  network *n5 = create_network(ip, 84);

  update_network(n1, n2, 10);
  update_network(n1, n3, 11);
  update_network(n1, n4, 11);
  update_network(n1, n5, 11);
}
```

Logs (Notice the random empty line that occurs in the last log?)

```
after heartbeat: 0.0.0.0:80
after localtime: 0.0.0.0:80
after heartbeat: 0.0.0.0:80
after localtime: 0.0.0.0:80
after heartbeat: 0.0.0.0:80
after localtime: 0.0.0.0:80
after heartbeat: 0.0.0.0:80
after localtime:
                 :80
```

Comment: Should we be worried that you added 80, 81, 82, 83, 84 (5 entries) and are getting back reports on 7 lots of 80 and one screwed up entry?  Why didn't it stop at 5 entries?  Why didn't the port numbers get handled properly?

Comment: Your data structure doesn't make a lot of sense. Instead of having N ips, N ports, N heartbeats, N local times, all of which must be in sync, why not have N simple entities, each having one ip, one port, one heartbeat and one local time? Here the reason of your problem is that you forgot to realloc localtime. With a sensible data structure like I propose you wouldn't have such a problem. There's only one realloc, and everything is automatically in sync.

Comment: Note that adding 1 entry per time you do a sequence of reallocs is not good for performance.  Note also that `current->heartbeat =
      realloc(current->heartbeat, sizeof(int) * current->count);` is a recipe for memory leaks when the memory reallocation fails.  Save the return value in a local variable; only assign to `current->heartbeat` (in this case) when you know the return value is non-null.  Otherwise, you zap the pointer to the memory and cannot release it again.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your comments. I'm new to C so this is all rather new...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reallocate `current->local_time` the same way you do reallocate the other fields of your `struct network` before assigning `current->local_time[current->count - 1] = local_time;` .